# Export to Excel using C# (in WebApplication) and identify the button pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, export-to-excel, keypress

I exported Excel code from `GridView` to Excel Sheet. I have a Download Dialog Dox. How do I get the button value whether the data is Saved/Downloaded or the Dialog Box is closed by hitting cancel button?

I want to identify the button pressed is <kbd>Save</kbd> or <kbd>Cancel</kbd> in the Download Dialog Box.

```cs
public void Export(GridView GridView1, DataTable dtGuid)
{
   
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=ScratchcardDetails.xls";

    Response.ClearContent();

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);

    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";


    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.Visible = true;
    GridView1.DataSource = dtGuid;
    GridView1.DataBind();


    // Create a form to contain the grid

    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
    this.GridView1.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
    frm.Controls.Add(this.GridView1);
    frm.RenderControl(htw);
    //Response.Write(style);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();

}
```

Comment: You need to provide code. Are you calling ShowDialog() that returns DialogResult, check for DialogResult.OK

Answer (score 0):

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Save hit
}
```